# Coco2d-x Android Studio Debug on Device & Emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, cocos2d-x, emulation, genymotion

Cocos2d-x 3.14.1, NDK r10c, android-19 (min 14, target 19), Java source & target 1.7, Open GL 2.0, build => x86, armeabi, aremabi-v7a

Mac, Android Studio 2.2.3, HAXM 6.8.1, Genymotion 2.8.1

I have built a 'new' Cocos2d-x project (Hello World) as above.

I can debug my application on an Android device ok - HTC m9.

Failing to run on my emulator Google Nexus 4 - 4.1.1 API 16.

```
D/cocos2d-x debug info: {
                            gl.supports_OES_packed_depth_stencil: true
                            gl.supports_vertex_array_object: false
                            gl.supports_BGRA8888: false
                            gl.supports_ATITC: false
                            gl.supports_S3TC: false
                            cocos2d.x.version: cocos2d-x-3.14.1
                            gl.supports_discard_framebuffer: false
                            cocos2d.x.compiled_with_profiler: false
                            gl.supports_PVRTC: false
                            cocos2d.x.build_type: DEBUG
                            gl.renderer: Android Emulator OpenGL ES Translator (NVIDIA GeForce 9400M OpenGL Engine)
                            gl.supports_OES_depth24: true
                            gl.supports_ETC1: true
                            gl.supports_OES_map_buffer: false
                            cocos2d.x.compiled_with_gl_state_cache: true
                            gl.version: OpenGL ES 2.0 (2.1 NVIDIA-10.0.51 310.90.10.05b12)
                            gl.supports_NPOT: true
                            gl.max_texture_units: 16
                            gl.vendor: Google (NVIDIA Corporation)
                            gl.max_texture_size: 8192
                        }
D/cocos2d-x debug info: create rendererRecreatedListener for GLProgramState
D/cocos2d-x debug info: create rendererRecreatedListener for GLProgramState
D/cocos2d-x debug info: create rendererRecreatedListener for GLProgramState
D/cocos2d-x debug info: create rendererRecreatedListener for GLProgramState
A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=128), thread 1352 (Thread-88)
```

Any clues how I can run on the emulator would be appreciated?!

Comment: Without some stack trace there'd be hard to guess what failed. Have you tried other (newer) emulators? Try using debug mode. Follow this: http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/how-to-link-prebuilt-cocos2d-x-c-library-to-android-studio-project/32949/11?u=piotrros

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.